# Are SVM generalization bounds valid if the kernel is learned on a different dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm

Suppose I have a training dataset with a binary label, and I do an 80/20 split on it. On the first 80% of the data, I train a deep learning embedding model that maps my data unto some higher dimensional space such the normalized distance between the centroids of each label group is maximized.

I then apply this mapping to the remaining 20% and train an SVM on the mapped data (the kernel being the dot product of the outputs of the embedding NN).

Question: Can I trust the generalization bounds of the SVM or have I violated some assumption of Statistical Learning Theory?